# Once I lose a villager's trade option, can I ever get it back?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Once you out-trade a villager's specific option, you lose it: it has a large red **X** on it, and you cannot make that particular trade anymore. Is there any way to recover options that fall to this fate?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you need to trade with them using one of their other trade options.

From the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trade#Functionality) (emphasis mine):

> Villagers will deactivate an offer if the offer has been used some number of times and it is not the villager's only offer. The chance of an offer's deactivation is random, but an offer must be used at least 3 times before it is eligible for deactivation. After an offer has been used 13 times, it is guaranteed to be deactivated if you close the interface after trading it (this is true even if all 13 trades have been done at once). **Trading the last offer may activate an offer again.**

Comment: **I like this answer and I would accept it;** don't know why Ender doesn't :/

Comment: *"Trading the last offer may activate an offer again"* is 100% correct. I have personally experienced this multiple times - trading the last offer resets one maxed out trade, however it will not if the villager does not introduce a new trade.

Comment: I have conducted experiments on actual villagers that suggests the same thing. I am getting consistent results that trading the last offer will reactivate all deactivated trades.

Comment: @Ender What is your determination relating to the bounty?

Comment: This answer is perfectly fine, there is not very much to say about this topic, therefore a bounty isn't really necessary, too.

Comment: *Trading the last offer may activate an offer again*, what if the offer deactivated is the **Last Offer**?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be able to use that offer again if you simply preform some other trades with that Villager specifically. To avoid the trade being blocked, simple make sure to not trade over 7 or so times at once and wait a while between trade sessions.

Answer (score 2):

When a villager goes to its trading station, for example a tool smith going to a smithing table, the villager replenishes his trades because he replenishes his stock.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have tested this theory and they get the red x because they're out of stock or you've traded too many times they need to refresh up there trade table that they use

Comment: What theory are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the mod. For **PE**: To let you trade again, **it will have to go to it's workstation block to restock**. For **Java**: It can only stock 2 times, **the next day it will reset and be able to stock again another 2 times**.

Comment: The workstation blocks for each profession: Fletching table if it's a Fletcher. Smokers for Butchers. Brewing Stand for Clerics. Blast Furnace for Armorers. Cartography Table for Cartographers. Composter for Farmers. Barrels for Fishermen. Cauldron for Leatherworkers. Lecterns for Librarians. Stonecutter for Stone Mason. Loom for Shepherds. Smithing Table for Tool Smiths. Grindstone for Weaponsmiths. Yes I searched this up. There's almost no way to remember. Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

it will replenish eventually if the villager gets to its job site block, but the items required to do the trade might have increased (or decreased)

Answer (score 0):

I play on a PlayStation, so for me there is no way to get a trade back. But I have learned that you may be able to get a trade back on different  devices where you simply do a higher trade and possibly get the other trade back.

Answer (score -6):

No, the specific trade that has an X on it is not able to be done again. The villager will have other trades, but that specific trade is unavailable forever.

Comment: _Squidward's voice:_ **This answer isn't elaborate enough. Can you put more effort into it? ;)**

Comment: This is from my own experience in Minecraft. I assume that is to simulate villagers running out of items to give you, but that is only a guess of mine and does not have a source.

Comment: This answer is completely inaccurate. If you complete the last trade with a villager, and he introduces a new trade, you can trade previously maxed out trades.

Comment: No, you can not. once a trade has become marked with an X, it is unable to be redone.

Comment: **Dun, dun, dunn....**

Comment: *Hello jacen,* look at your score, now back to Steven's, now back at your score, now back to his. Sadly, your answer is *clearly* rejected, but if you switched your answer to an actually correct one, your score could be like his!